# Remove duplicates from rows in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a set of records highlighting the keywords with regards to the dates they were raised. I want to remove the duplicates in the rows and analyze the frequency of keywords on a pivot table with regards to the month they were raised.

I have used python-3 code to chunk out the keywords from the customer queries that were logged in the system. I am not sure how to strip it.

```
Sub RemoveDuplicatesInRow()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim r As Long 'row index
    Dim c As Long 'column index
    Dim i As Long

    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        lastRow = .Row + .Rows.Count - 1
        lastCol = .Column + .Columns.Count - 1
    End With

    For r = 1 To lastRow
        For c = 1 To lastCol
            For i = c + 1 To lastCol 'change lastCol to c+2 will remove adjacent duplicates only
                If Cells(r, i) <> "" And Cells(r, i) = Cells(r, c) Then
                    Cells(r, i) = ""
                End If
            Next i
        Next c
    Next r

End Sub
```

The macro just doesn't work.

Comment: Hi & welcome to the forum. Could you please paste a sample of your data and explain why your "macro doesn't work"? It worked fine for me for the following sample: cells `A1:A3` values: "a", "b", "c"; cells `B1:B3`: "c", "b", "a". After running your macro, duplicate value "b" in cell `B2` was removed. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I wouldn’t reinvent the wheel since I think you could easily use `Range().RemoveDuplicates()`